# Split a multiline file into Terraform variable to access the values by their keys

Tags: terraform, hcl

I have a third-party maintained file with a lot of lines and it looks like:

```
# a comment lines
aaa.bbb.cc 423 
ddd.ee.fff 452
...
tons.like.them 111
```

Is there any way to load the file to a local map and access its keys in Terraform using the syntax like?:

```
"${lookup(var.locals.mylist, 'ddd.ee.fff', 0)}"
```

Comment: Probably involves a `local-exec` with some kind of script/manipulation.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying this option right now and looks like it is a perspective choice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's often better to pre-process files like this using a separate program written in a general-purpose programming language, since Terraform's DSL is not well-suited for this sort of ad-hoc parsing logic.

Terraform v0.11 and earlier lack the primitives required to implement parsing like this within the language itself. The v0.12.0 release (which is [in beta](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/announcing-terraform-0-1-2-beta1) at the time of writing) introduces some primitives that *do* allow this sort of parsing to be implemented, though I would still generally prefer to do it outside of Terraform as a preprocessing step if at all possible.

With that said, here's an example of parsing a file like your example into a map using Terraform v0.12 features:

```
locals {
  raw_lines = [
    for line in split("\n", file("${path.module}/input.txt")) :
    split(" ", trimspace(line))
  ]
  lines = [
    for line in local.raw_lines :
    line if length(line[0]) > 0 && substr(line[0], 0, 1) != "#"
  ]
  records = { for line in local.lines : line[0] => line[1] }
}

output "result" {
  value = local.records
}
```

Given the following input file:

```
# a comment line
aaa.bbb.cc 423 
ddd.ee.fff 452
tons.like.them 111

# another comment
another.record abc
```

This produces the following result using Terraform v0.12.0-beta1:

```
$ terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

result = {
  "aaa.bbb.cc" = "423"
  "another.record" = "abc"
  "ddd.ee.fff" = "452"
  "tons.like.them" = "111"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Very nice answer for 0.12. I'm marking this as a solution even though I can't test it right now. But v0.12 is a big step forward for Terraform and I hope that it will be released soon.

Answer (score 0):

The file name is `myfile.txt` and the content is:

```
# a comment line
aaa.bbb.cc 423 
ddd.ee.fff 452
...
tons.like.them 111
```

The data query should look like:

```
data "external" "myfile" {
  program = [
    "bash",
    "${path.module}/template/parser.sh",
    "${path.module}/template/myfile.txt",
    "ddd.ee.fff"
  ]
}
```

And the `template/parser.sh` contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eo pipefail

CONFIG=$(cat $1|grep -v '#' | sed 's/ /=/g' | jq -R -n -c '.data = ([inputs|split("=")|{(.[0]):.[1]}] |add)')

OUTPUT=$(echo $CONFIG | jq -r '.data["'$2'"]')
jq -n --arg output "$OUTPUT" '{"output":$output}'
```

This tricky script will return:

```
{"output": 452}
```

And the interpolation can be used to get the resulting value:

```
${data.external.myfile.result.output}
```

Unfortunately I didn't find how to load the full list of rows into Terraform and access them using "variable of variable" or lookup(). If the bash scripts return the result of the first `jq` call, Terraform throws the exception:

```
command "bash" produced invalid JSON: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type string
```

**Update2:** To access the resulting values, you need to use an additional key ".result" before the actual ".output" key from the script.

Comment: hey, how can we get the list of values or the list of key-value pairs.. 
I've `{"privateIpAddress":"10.48.131.30"} {"privateIpAddress":"10.48.131.34"}` this and I would like to extract the ip addresses alone & process them further..